# How to synchronise AUTOSAR RTE write and read values with different task runnable?

Tags: events, operating-system, embedded, rte, autosar

I am new to `AUTOSAR` and I would like to call a `RTE` function to get a specific value from one `SWC` to another `SWC`. The `RTE_Write` is performing by one `SWC 1` `runnable` with `10 msec` task and `RTE_read` is performing by another `SWC 2` with `15 msec task`. I am using `sender receiver interface` to implement this concept.

```
SWC 1 :

Task_10msec()
{
  eg:

  int val = 0;
  val = val +1 ; 
  Rte_write_test_port(val);
}

SWC 2 :

Task_15msec()
{
  eg:

  int val = 0;
  Rte_read_test_port(&val);
}
```

Now here i am facing the problem is that `RTE_read` value is not `sync` with `RTE_Write` value because of the runnable timing (`SWC 1` is `10 msec` and `SWC 2` is `15 msec`). I would like to know, is there any way to design the interface/ any approach to get the exact read value in SWC 2 after writing from SWC 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a `QueuedReceiverComSpec` on the receiver port and set the `queueLength` to e.g. 2. You should then use `Rte_Receive` instead of `Rte_Read` API and read until it returns `RTE_E_NO_DATA` in order to get all values provided by the other component.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve?

Shall the receiver only get the **latest** value written by the sender? Then your solution is already sufficient.

Shall the receiver get **all** values that the sender wrote to the interface? Then you need to introduce a queue on the receiver port. In the receiver runnable, you can then read all elements in the queue until it is empty.

For more details, check the [AUTOSAR RTE specification](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-2/AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE.pdf) (chapter 4.3.1).